# nodejs + sqlite: query execution order

Tags: node.js, sqlite, execution

With Sqlite with nodejs you can't take the call execution order equals to the real db execution order of a query.
For example in this pseuso-code you cannot predict if will be inserted A before B or viceversa:

```
function() {
    db.run("INSERT A", function() { });
    db.run("INSERT B", function() { });
}
```

But what about the execution order of the callbacks? If the callback of the INSERT A will be called before the callback of INSERT B you can deduce that A will be inserter before B ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the code execution is started then all the callbacks is passed to `event queue` in `FIFO` order and event queue watch the current stack execution and if the stack is empty then instantly pass the `first  position's callback` to `stack`.

So in your case, if the `INSERT A` callback is called then it executed first after that `INSERT B` callback executed.

Here is recommended `YouTube link` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ to understand the `event loop` properly you can take a lot of ideas from here since this Guy explained everything in a suitable way

Comment: Thank you! I'm watching this good video. So i can take the execution order of callbacks as the real db execution order.